# Why is there no Kaddish after Torah reading at mincha on a fast day?

Tags: tefilla, fast-days, torah-service, kaddish, mincha-afternoon-prayer

Every Torah reading is followed by half Kaddish, except for Shabbat and fast day mincha.

Mishnah Berurah #4 on [O.C. 292:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%91_%D7%90) says that on Shabbat and fast days we don't say Kaddish after Torah reading because there is really nothing interrupting the Torah reading and the Kaddish that's said just before *Amidah*, so that Kaddish works for the one that should be said after Torah reading.

This reasoning seems to work for Shabbat. But, on fast days a haftarah is said. WHy does Mishnah Berurah not consider that as a *hefsek* (interruption)?

Comment: The bigger question is why on Tisha Bav morning is Kaddish said before the Haftara and not after, but on fast day Mincha it's said after and not before. This is a hotly debated issue in Acharonim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Magen Avrraham OC 292 SK 2

The reason is that there is nothing between the eventually (and not existing)  kaddich after the third ole and the kaddich before Tefilah shmona esre. The source is in in Hagahot Maymoniot. The Sefer Hapardes says that the Kaddich before the shmona esre plays for the end of kriat Hatora, despite the interruption by gelila. The Rivash says that if there is no Sefer to read, they don't need to say the Kaddich before Shmona esre. This last din is controversial.
**Regarding fasts, the Hagahot Maymoniot says that the maftir is not after the end of kria but he is the acharon. There is no reason to say Kaddich after the Levi because the kria is not finished. In the middle of the presence of the maftir,  this is not possible because the ole hasn't finished.**

> ג' אנשים:    וא"א קדיש על התורה שאין כאן במה להפסיק בין קדיש זה לקדיש שקודם י"ח ואפי' במנחה בתענית שמפטירין אין כאן הפסק דהפטרה שייכא אל הקריאה (הגמ"נ) וכ"כ בליקוטי פרד"ס שהקדיש שלפני י"ח קאי אקריא' ואף על פי שמפסיקין בין הקריא' לקדיש עד שיגלול ס"ת לא חשיב הפסק דסיומא אריכת' היא עכ"ל וכ"מ בלבוש וכתב הריב"ש סי' שנ"א דבמקום שאין ס"ת א"א קדיש שלפני י"ח ונ"ל שלא יאמרו ג"כ ואני תפלתי כמש"ל וגם שלא להפסיק בין הקדיש שאחר ובא לציון לתפל' י"ח וא"ל שיאמרו ואני תפלתי ויאמרו קדיש עליו דפסוק א' לא חשיב הפסק מידי דהוי איהללו או יאמרוהו קוד' הקדיש וכ"כ בסידור מהרר"ה שלעולם לא יתחילו י"ח בלא קדיש שלפניו:‏